# How to call notifyDataSetChanged() from within AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-adapter

I have an `ArrayAdapter` and within it an `AsyncTask` but I'm not sure how to call `notifyDataSetChanged` from the `onPostExecute`

Example:

```
public class ColorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Color> {

  List<Color> colorList;
  Context context;
  ....

  public ColorAdapter(Context context, List<Color> list) {
    this.context = context; this.colorList = list;  
  }

  public View getView (final int position, final View view, final ViewGroup parent) { 
   .....
  }

  class DeleteColorTask extends AsyncTask <String, String, String> {
   int colorId;
   DeleteColorTask (int colorId) {this.colorId = colorId;} 

   protected String doInBackgroud (String ... args) {
     //call to server to delete the color
     colorList.remove(colorList.indexOf(...));
   }
   protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
     //HOW CAN I CALL notifyDataSetChanged() here?? this.notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't work since I am inside DeleteColorTask class
   }
  }
}
```

I call the above from my activity like this:

```
  adapter = new ColorAdapter(context, colorsList);
  setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: You could make a void to call `notifyDataSetChanged` inside your main class and make the `onPostExecute` call that void.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call it like this:

```
ColorAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

As an aside, a more appropriate place to launch this `AsyncTask` would be from it's host fragment/activity, why?
AsyncTasks sometimes tend to stick around longer than you expect, if you don't manage their lifecycle appropriately they can cause trouble.

Comment: hmm the only real i have this AsyncTask in the adapter class is because a button on each row of the list can delete that item. So I'm forced to put it inside my custom ArrayAdapter.

Comment: You haven't posted the entire code, but from what it looks if you're only removing an item from a List, I don't think you need an AsyncTask for that. If you could elaborate on what you're trying to do, there might be a better solution for your problem.

Comment: I'm removing an item from the list but the deletion has to happen on the server side as well. So each time i remove an item from the list I have to make a DELETE REST call to my server code as well and that I thought can only be made from an AsyncTask

Comment: That is really out of the Adapter's scope.. You can issue the REST request from your activity/fragment, there you will be able to either remove the data immediately from the adapter (before you get the response) or for instance show a progress dialog and change the data in the adapter once you got the response from network. Whatever path you choose, launching the task from an activity or fragment will allow you to cancel it in certain cases (i.e. user hits back button), that will also reduce unnecessary battery usage.